# Azure Kinect DK operating range

Tags: azure, sensors, azurekinect

I have a question regarding the specified operating range of the Azure Kinect DK given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/hardware-specification), under the "Depth camera supported operating modes" section. The operating range numbers are given for various modes (e.g. In WFOV 2x2 binnned mode, the operating range is 0.25 to 2.88 meters), but the operating range column has an asterisk which states "*15% to 95% reflectivity". What I was hoping to find out was the following:

Does operating range of 0.25 - 2.88 meters at 15 - 95% reflectivity mean that its max range is 0.25 meters when a target has a reflectivity of 15%, and 2.88 meters at 95% reflectivity, or can the Azure Kinect DK still reliably see targets with 15% reflectivity at 2.88 meters?

I tried calling Microsoft support regarding this question, but unfortunately they directed me to portal.azure.com, so I'm hoping to get an official Microsoft answer regarding this question, if possible. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it means the opposite. The Azure Kinect can image a 95% reflective object up to the near distance (0.25m for WFOV 2x2 binned) without over exposing, and it can image a 15% reflective object out to the far distance (2.88m for WFOV 2x2 binned).

Comment: Thanks QM13, do you possibly have a source for this data?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/hardware-specification#depth-camera-supported-operating-modes